# AngularJS ngRepeat orderBy in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple app that shows rows of data in Angular.  When the controller is initially loaded with data, I want the rows to appear in the same order they were added to my `rows` array.  So, the `orderBy` property will initially be set to an empty string.  Clicking on the column header should then set the `orderBy` property to the appropriate value.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLjMR/3/.

Here's my JS:

```
function ctrl($scope)
{
    var rows = [];
    for(var i = 10;i < 30;i++)
    {
        rows.push({name: "Fake Name " + i, email: "fakeemail" + i + "@gmail.com"});
    }

    $scope.rows = rows;
    $scope.orderBy = "";
};
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<table ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
    <thead>
        <th><a ng-click="orderBy='name'">Name</a></th>
        <th><a ng-click="orderBy='email'">Email</a></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:[orderBy]">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.email}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I do this in IE and FF, the rows intially appear in the order they were added, but when I do it in Chrome, the middle item (in this case row #20) appears at the beginning of the list.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one property that you order by then you can pass just the string to the filter rather than an array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:orderBy">
```

Comment: Huh.  Well what do you know, that fixed it.  I was aware you could get rid of the brackets, but I was planning on adding some additional parameters later on.  Why would the brackets make a difference?

Comment: Just took a peek at the angular source. The orderByFilter short circuits if the sort predicate (the thing after the colon) is a falsy value and returns the array unsorted. An empty string is a falsy value. An array containing an empty string is not a falsy value so a sort is attempted using that empty string as a predicate.

Comment: Great stuff.  I think you nailed it!  Thanks a lot!