# AngularJS orderBy - crazy Array.prototype.sort behaviour in Chromium browsers - Cannot clear sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

There is something that drives me nuts in a project of mine.

I have some code pretty similar to this (I have tried to make it as similar to mine as possible, with all the JS files I use, etc, but the code in this Plnkr doesn't seem to matter anyway as you will see because I cannot reproduce it there...):
http://plnkr.co/edit/SCUCsxLgu2zFzMhZ0whs?p=preview

My issue is that when I set `predicate=''` the sorting is not 100% cleared. Angular seemed to change the order of my elements like that (this picture is with `predicate=''`):

[image]

When I removed the `orderBy`, everything was in its order (like it was serverd from my repository). After trying millions of different things with `orderBy` I could not make it clear the sort entirely.

I have found this case that had some similarities to mine: [AngularJS ngRepeat orderBy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343168/angularjs-ngrepeat-orderby-in-chrome#), but it turns out that my case is not related to that issue.

I am a patient guy, so I went into the `angular.js` file (AngularJS v1.3.15) and started debugging. This is the most crucial line:

```
return slice.call(array).sort(reverseComparator(comparator, reverseOrder));
```

Up until `slice.call(array)` the array is well ordered. When `sort` was executed the result was wrong. So I did this:

```
function comparator(o1, o2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sortPredicate.length; i++) {
    var comp = sortPredicate[i](o1, o2);
    if (comp !== 0){
      console.log(7);  // <---------------------
      return comp;
    }
  }
  console.log(0);      // <---------------------
  return 0;
}

function reverseComparator(comp, descending) {
  return descending
      ? function(a, b) {return comp(b,a);}
      : comp;
}
```

And guess what: All I get in my console when the `predicate=''` is zeros.
Also, typing :

```
slice.call(array).sort
```

...returns:

```
function sort() { [native code] }
```

So, I have no idea why this sorting happens.
And it seems that it only happens in Chromium-based browsers (I have tried Chrome and Opera). FF and IE11 clear the sort as expected.

Now, I would think that this was a Chromium bug, but I still haven't managed to reproduce it in that Plnkr and I wonder why (perhaps something different in the data?)...

I have also tried disabling my Chrome extensions, but that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Chromium and Angular are both famous now. Has anyone else noticed this before?

Does anyone have ANY idea what's wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

OK. I think I have managed to reproduce it by adding more items to my array. See here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SCUCsxLgu2zFzMhZ0whs?p=preview

(party time! :D)

I'm gonna go and report it to the Angular team. They're Google. They might fix Chromium as well. :D

Comment: documentation does not say anything about predicate='', but example does. may be some think it works and added as example.

Comment: i cheked your updaed plunker, everything seems to work fine.. what is the issue

Comment: @entre If you notice the displayed table, the two first rows are "John"s **if you use Chrome**, despite the fact that `predicate` is an empty string. That's what's wrong.

Comment: @YOU The docs say this: `If no property is provided, (e.g. '+') then the array element itself is used to compare where sorting.`. And: `If the predicate is missing or empty then it defaults to '+'.`. One would at least expect the same behavior cross-browser, but that's not the case. But the problem seems more fundamental to me since it involves the implementation of the JS `sort` function itself , which should have been standardized by now...

Comment: And, of course, there is the performance consideration: Since `predicate` is empty and `array` is an array of objects, why the hack Angular does all that useless stuff behind the scenes? And the design part: If this thing is supposed to sort no-matter-what, how could one clear the sorting? The solution would be to create a custom filter, but `orderBy` is a fundamental Angular building block and one would expect it to be better than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that I will finally adopt is using these custom filters:

```
(function () {

    function isNullOrEmpty(str) {
        return str === '' || str === undefined || str === null;
    }

    angular.module('CustomFilters', [])
        .filter('okOrderBy', ['$filter', function ($filter) {

            return function (array, predicate, reverse) {
                if (isNullOrEmpty(predicate)) return array;
                return $filter('orderBy')(array, predicate, reverse);
            };
        }
        ])
        .filter('arrayOrderBy', [function () {

            function Comparator(predicate, reverse) {
                return reverse ? function (a, b) {
                    a = a[predicate];
                    b = b[predicate];
                    if (a === b) return 0;
                    return a < b ? 1 : -1;
                } : function (a, b) {
                    a = a[predicate];
                    b = b[predicate];
                    if (a === b) return 0;
                    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
                };
            }

            return function (array, predicate, reverse) {
                if (isNullOrEmpty(predicate)) return array;
                return array.slice(0).sort(new Comparator(predicate, reverse));
            };
        }
        ]);

})();
```

The second one is independent of Angular filters and I like it more.

But it works only for arrays of objects, with predicates that are property names only, and does not allow "multiple column" sorts.
While the first should work for everything (I guess).

I had a great dilemma on which answer I should accept because all other answers were helpful and interesting. I wish I could vote them more than once out of appreciation. I am thinking of choosing this answer (I know... I am selfish...) just because it solves the problem and it is shorter to use than the one provided by user "YOU".

Comment: you don't have to accept other answer, if you don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11)

> The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order).

So it's **not** a bug in the browser.

The Angular code does consider an empty predicate:

```
if (predicate === '') {
  // Effectively no predicate was passed so we compare identity
  return reverseComparator(compare, descending);
}
```

With the `compare` function being

```
function compare(v1, v2) {
  var t1 = typeof v1;
  var t2 = typeof v2;
  if (t1 === t2 && t1 === "object") {
    v1 = objectToString(v1);
    v2 = objectToString(v2);
  }
  ...
```

and `objectToString` being

```
function objectToString(value) {
  if (value === null) return 'null';
  if (typeof value.valueOf === 'function') {
    value = value.valueOf();
    if (isPrimitive(value)) return value;
  }
  if (typeof value.toString === 'function') {
    value = value.toString();
    if (isPrimitive(value)) return value;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Since your objects neither have their **own** `valueOf` or `toString` methods they end up being equal (the function will probably return `"[object Object]"`). Which brings us back to the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: I have seen these parts of the Angular code and noticed the `[object Object]` being returned, but I've missed the 'stable' part in the specs. I wonder why people put these kind of things in the specs... How do people sort in a reliable way those days on the web? Since adding `valueOf` or `toString` on my objects doesn't sound like a viable solution, I will either have to change the code of Angular or find a way to override the `Array.prototype.sort` itself (as dangerous as this is considered to be)...

Comment: Please keep in mind that in your case you wouldn't call `sort` in the first place. In most other cases the order of equal elements shouldn't matter. You also reported that it takes a larger amount of equal elements to get undesired results. The missing requirement of being stable could result in faster algorithms.

Comment: Yes, in my case I wouldn't need to call `sort`. But Angular does call it (for reasons that are beyond my imagination at the moment), so this indeed seems to be an Angular issue. I think I will go in `angular.js` and change that. I also don't know if the extra elements triggered the problem or if they just made it apparent (I had many duplicates in my array and there is a chance that they were ordered wrongly even when they seemed to be OK - probably I should have used numbered items like in the picture above to make things clearer).

Comment: But the speed indeed may have been the reason for the specs formation. I just hate having to either test everything under all browsers or learn all the weirdness of the specs by heart to avoid those situations (hoping of course that all browsers do follow the specs to every detail). I might get used to that at some point in time, but if the Angular team hasn't managed to do that yet, I don't know what are my chances...

Comment: Angular calls `sort` because no predicate means that elements are sorted by their natural order. The example in the docs may be a bit misleading, because unsorted in that case actually means not having a particular order and not - as one might think - keeping the original order.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Don't let sorting run when you don't want.

Glad angular let you write anything there.

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in (predicate ? (friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse) : friends)">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KIdAKPtA3JDtRMDD50VI?p=preview